# Nginx stat() failed (13: Permission Denied)

Tags: php, wordpress, unix, nginx

Okay so there have been some previous posting of this yet no solution fixes my problem.

I have site configured which is just straight up HTML, CSS & JS and I'm trying to add a wordpress site. My config for the wordpress site is as follows.

```
#######################

server {
listen 80;

root /usr/share/nginx/threadtheatre/wordpress;
index index.php;
server_name threadtheatre.co.uk;

access_log   /var/log/nginx/thread.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/thread.error.log;

location / {

            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

This is the error thats in my logs

```
"/usr/share/nginx/threadtheatre/wordpress/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 109.155.53.189, server: threadtheatre.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "threadtheatre.co.uk"
```

nginx is using the nginx user and likewise for php-fpm. The nginx directory and all its sub directories have the following permissions.

```
drwxrwxr-x.  3 root nginx  4096 Feb  8 18:23 ..
```

If I browse to threadtheatre.co.uk on the web i get 404.

hope someone can help with this.

Lee.

Comment: What operating system is being used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for me  this is because selinux enabled, check with

```
selinuxenabled && echo enabled || echo disabled
```

if enabled try to disable

```
nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux
SELINUX=disabled
```

then

```
reboot
```

Answer (score 11):

Do you still have this problem? This explanation worked for me: 
https://serverfault.com/a/170263/140684

basically nginx needs to have execution rights on every dir on the path to your app. Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me too. Counter-intuitive (I thought read permissions were enough, but nginx needs `+x` for directories).

Comment: That's not specific nginx, it's a generic linux thing (or even for unix, not sure). Permissions on directories behave a bit different than for files. The `x` bit for directories is called the search bit and is required to be able to enter the directory and access the files and directories in it. You can try for yourself by creating a directory, remove the `x` bit (`chmod a-x <dir>`) and then try to `cd` into it.

Comment: This is the answer...nginx needs to have execution rights to every dir on the path to your app...very weird

Answer (score -1):

If `nginx` is hosted on `Fedora` or `RedHat` , change the `SELinux` policy and allow `nginx` to serve from the path **/home/path/site**

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/path/site
```